# Cellular data not working after software update?

Tags: software, cellular-data

I have updated my iphone software to 6.1 on my 3GS and now my cellular data network is not available. Can this be fixed or can I restore an earlier version again?

Comment: I would be interested to know if your carrier could help you with this? Also, 6.1.1 is the latest update - for at least iPhone 4S (not sure about the 3GS). Make sure there are no updates available. I know 6.1.1 was supposed to help with some connection problems. What carrier are you with?

Answer (score 1):

I contacted my carrier (o2) and issue was resolved easily. It appears that Data Bolt-On, that I subscribe to, was no longer iPhone compatible. I was advised that this setting was affected by the Software Update. Not sure I really understand how or why but I was assured that the setting had now been amended and data services would be restored at midnight tonight

Answer (score -2):

Did you check your settings for your APN? Since iOS 6 it tends to clear the value on random times for some people.
You can check this within Settings > General > Cellular > Cellular Data Network > APN.

You can only edit this setting if your carrier allows this.
More info here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2283

Comment: There is no such setting on my iPhone with iOS 6 (the > Cellular Data Network > APN part). Try going to this site and loading the necessary settings for your carrier: http://www.unlockit.co.nz/unlockit/

Comment: The option is only available for unlocked iPhones

Comment: My phone is unlocked and doesn't have that option. Do you mean jailbroken phones? Or do you mean the APN setting from the website?

Comment: With some carriers it's editable with no extra configuration. So without jailbreaking your device.It's a setting that is carrier dependent. You can find additional info here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2283